# Unable to use UdpClient to multicast to "239.255.255.250"

Tags: uwp, multicast, udpclient, multicastsocket

```
    string sMulticastAddress = "239.255.255.250";
    UdpClient uc = new UdpClient();
    uc.JoinMulticastGroup(IPAddress.Parse(sMulticastAddress));
    IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(sMulticastAddress), 3702);
    byte[] abFoo = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is a test");
    for (int i= 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        uc.Send(abFoo, abFoo.Length, iep);
    }
```

The above code runs, but it does not seem to send out anything based on the trace of Wireshark. However, if I change sMulticastAddress to any other address such as 239.255.255.251, 239.255.255.248, 239.255.255.249, it works perfectly. Wireshark captures every packet("This is a test") sent by it.
I do not know what makes 239.255.255.250 so special.  I am testing it on Windows 10.  I have tried turning off Firewall.  This is a UWP app.
I have another UWP app that uses DatagramSocket to multicast to the same address on the same computer, and it works. This means the problem is probably related to UdpClient.
I am wondering if anyone could offer a tip on the possible causes.

Comment: 239.255.255.250 is the address of the [SSDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol) protocol. Perhaps UWP is "protecting" you...

Comment: As I mentioned, another UWP app with exactly the same configuration works fine.  It uses DatagramSocket.

Comment: Why the port is 3702 but not 1900?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Discovery

Comment: I don't find `UdpClient` class in uwp document, could share more about it, and in uwp we often use  `DatagramSocket` to send UDP packets, Why do you use `UdpClient` ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I am developing UWP with Uno platform: https://platform.uno/  This is interesting.